# Segfault when installing custom IMessageFilter in Python.net app

Tags: python, winforms, python.net

I'm trying to add a custom `IMessageFilter` in a Winforms app using Python.net, but I'm getting a segfault.

Here's a minimal sample application:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
import System.Windows.Forms as WinForms


class MessageFilter(WinForms.IMessageFilter):
    __namespace__ = 'System.Windows.Forms'

    def PreFilterMessage(self, message):
        print('filter', message)
        return False


class HelloApp(WinForms.Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.textbox = WinForms.TextBox()
        self.textbox.Text = "Hello World"
        self.Controls.Add(self.textbox)


def main():
    form = HelloApp()
    app = WinForms.Application
    f = MessageFilter()
    app.AddMessageFilter(f)
    app.Run(form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you run this code as presented, the application window displays, but you get a segfault immediately (I presume this is when the first message is passed to the filter). The segfault is entirely opaque. There's no stack trace or other helpful details - it's just the OS-level segfault handler.

If you comment out line 25 (`app.AddMessageFilter(f)`, installing the actual filter), the code works fine.

If you modify `MessageFilter` so that it doesn't subclass `Winforms.IMessageFilter`, you get an error saying there's no `AddMessageFilter` method matching the given arguments.

If you rename or remove the `PreFilterMessage()` method, you get an error that the Python object doesn't have a `PreFilterMessage` method.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong, and/or how to fix it? Or how to get more debugging information that could point at the source of the segfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug in Python.net itself, relating to a problem with marshaling `byref` arguments. Details can be found [here](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/965).